# Xcode 7 - Appirater on iOS9

Tags: ios9, xcode7, rate, review, appirater

I am using Appirator code which is an awesome tool. However I am running into an issue with iOS 9 when the review/rating is requested. It will only load the view for the app rather then pre-loading the "write a review" page. The following works perfectly with iOS8.

```
NSString *templateReviewURLiOS8 = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=APP_ID&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What device are you testing this on? I just tested it on an iPod touch running iOS 9, with the existing template URL and it took me straight to the reviews page in the app store app.

Comment: @ArashPayan I am running it on an iPhone 6 Plus with the latest version of iOS 9.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need update your URL depend of iOS version.

```
NSString *str;
float ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
 if (ver >= 7.0 && ver < 7.1) {
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@", appId];
} else if (ver >= 8.0) {
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=%@", appId];
} else {
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=%@", appId];
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested but the link provided above does not load the iTunes Store. The link for iOS 8 does load the store but does not bring up the "Review" page as it does with iOS 8.

Comment: mmmm. So weird. I recently updated one of my apps with those lines and bring me App page in App Store. Not review as is but bring the app page.

Comment: Yea it brings up the App page but not the "Write a Review" In iOS 8, it will bring everything up for the user so as they don't have to hit that. It makes the user less likely to abandon the review.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=919745844&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Above takes me to the current version reviews page.

I assume you're using the [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:] method inside Appirater instead of using in-app SKStoreProductViewController since you're passing that url. On iPhone 5C with iOS 9.0.1 built with Xcode 7.0.1 the openURL with you URL does in fact work and open the reviews page.

Do you have any reviews for the current version of your app?

I do not believe there is a way to display review page using SKStoreProductViewController.

Comment: I have not released the updated version for iOS9. I was testing it on my phone when it would only bring up the App page rather than the page where the user can select the stars and comment.

Comment: Still not following you. I have apps using Appirater that were built against the iOS 8 SDK (not iOS 9) where the above url format still takes user to reviews page with "Write a review" button there on iOS 9 devices.

Comment: I will run it on another device tonight. It may be something funky with my phone. I appreciate the input.

Comment: Np. I think we're still good to go using previous Appirater code for now. *whew*